# How do you remove developer capabilities from your Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I would like to remove all developer capabilities from my Facebook account, but cannot get a clear sense of how to do this (after much searching).

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please elaborate what you mean exactly with "developer capabilties"?

You could remove the Facebook Apps such as "Developer" and "Graph API Explorer" here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Furthermore you can remove yourself from every app you created under the "Role" submenu of the app overview here:https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Answer (score 0):

This helps me in disabling the developers facebook account. First you need to delete any apps that is associated with your account, Watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj3Qk5DP1NM

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Links are welcomed on SO, but should always come with an explanation why this works, as well as the essential information behind the link. This because links tend to break over time.